# Error in -`*tmp*` : invalid argument to unary operator

Tags: r

No line number is given, for the error, in an R script.  Googling didn't help.
What's the problem?

Comment: Even if you answer your question yourself, it should conform to the standards expected at Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 15):

I had meant to put this line in the script:

`# -----------`

but instead it was this line.

`-----------`