# "Error in -`*tmp*` : invalid argument to unary operator" with URL

Tags: r, url, input

My code is as follows:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------
## 1. PACKAGES INSTALLATION AND ACTIVATION

#install.packages(keras)
#install.packages(tensorflow)
#install.packages(neuralnet)
#install.packages(httr)
#install.packages(RCurl)
#install.packages(readxl)
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)
library(neuralnet)
library(httr)
library(RCurl)
library(readxl)

------------------------------------------------------------------------
## 2. DATA PREPROCESSING
# Get data
url <-"https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00350/default%20of%20credit%20card%20clients.xls"
GET(url, write_disk("default.xls", overwrite=TRUE))
dataset <- read_xls('default.xls', sheet = 1, skip = 1)
```

And this is the error in console:

```
+ ## 2. DATA PREPROCESSING
+ # Get data
+   url <-"https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/machine-learning-databases/00350/default%20of%20credit%20card%20clients.xls"
Error in -`*tmp*` : invalid argument to unary operator
> GET(url, write_disk("default.xls", overwrite=TRUE))
Error in as.character(url) : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'character'
> dataset <- read_xls('default.xls', sheet = 1, skip = 1)
```

I have no idea where the "tmp" is in my code to fix. Could anyone help me please?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Oh thank you so much! Now I understand why I did it wrong!

Answer (score 0):

The line `-----` needs a `#` as first character. Otherwise it is interpreted as code, not as a comment. See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36589928/error-in-tmp-invalid-argument-to-unary-operator)